# CSS text-shadow inherited color on keyframes

Tags: css, css-animations

I need to apply the class .shglow to several texts with colored shadow so it can glow. I tried on keyframe with color property initial or without color at all. How to make this work only with css ?

```
<div class="sh_3 shglow">Glow this red shadow</div>
<div class="sh_4 shglow">Glow this blue shadow</div>

.sh_3{text-shadow:1px 1px 1px red}
.sh_4{text-shadow:1px 1px 1px blue}
.shglow{animation:shglow .5s infinite alternate;}

@keyframes shglow
{
    0% {text-shadow:0 0 3px inherit;}
    50% {text-shadow:0 0 13px inherit;}
    100% {text-shadow:0 0 23px inherit;}
}
```

Comment: No can do without modifying the HTML or using JavaScript.

Comment: @BoltClock yes we can with CSS :) https://stackoverflow.com/a/49351158/8620333

Comment: @Temani Afif: Oh, right, variables.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using CSS variables:

```css
.sh_3 {
  --c: red;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px var(--c);
}

.sh_4 {
  --c: blue;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px var(--c);
}

.shglow {
  animation: shglow .5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes shglow {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px var(--c, yellow);
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 13px var(--c, yellow);
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 23px var(--c, yellow);
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sh_3 shglow">Glow this red shadow</div>
<div class="sh_4 shglow">Glow this blue shadow</div>
<div class="shglow">Default one</div>
```

You may also don't specify color so the default one will be considered and the default one is the color of the element. By the way, with this solution you are obliged to change the color of the element.

```css
.sh_3 {
  color: red;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px;
}

.sh_4 {
  color: blue;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px;
}

.shglow {
  animation: shglow .5s infinite alternate;
}

@keyframes shglow {
  0% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px;
  }
  50% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 13px;
  }
  100% {
    text-shadow: 0 0 23px;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="sh_3 shglow">Glow this red shadow</div>
<div class="sh_4 shglow">Glow this blue shadow</div>
<div class="shglow">Default one</div>
```